# A little question about basic inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a \le X \le a$,

$a < X \le a$,

$a \le X < a$,

$a < X < a$.

What is X equal to?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $a\le X$ and $X\le A$ means $X=a$.   The other statements imply $a<a,$ which doesn't make sense

Comment: What do *you* think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inequalities are transitive.

$a < b < c\implies a< b$ and $b < c \implies a < c$.

So $a \le X \le a \implies a \le X$ and $X \le a \implies a\le a$.

And $a < X \le a \implies a < X$ and $X \le a \implies a < a$.

And $a \le X < a \implies a \le X$ and $X < a \implies a < a$.

And $a < X < a\implies a < X$ and $X < a\implies a < a$.

.....

So, you tell us, what does $X$ equal?

Comment: in the light of previous answer I agree with, my question would be" for what X is a either less than or equal to a in the first instance or is a less than a in the subsequent three instances?"

Comment: The first statement is valid, X = a.  All of the remaining statements are false.

Answer (score 0):

For real numbers $a\leq b$, the notations $[a,b]$, $(a,b]$, $[a,b)$, and $(a,b)$ are used for the intervals of real numbers satisfying the four types of inequalities you have written. When $a=b$, we have that
$$
[a,a]=\{a\},\quad (a,a]=[a,a)=(a,a)=\varnothing
$$
where $\varnothing$ denotes the empty set.